# Updating a Column based on 3 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join, sql-update

I have 3 tables such as

IndentHeader:

```
 IndentID        StatusID 
--------         ------   
    1             5      
    2             5
```

IndentDetail:

```
IndentID         ItemID           ItemStatusID
--------         ------           ------------
 1                22                 4
 1                23                 4
 2                11                 4
 2                12                 3
 2                13                 3
```

POIndent:

```
       POID             IndentID     ItemID      ItemStatusID
      --------           ------      ------      ------------
         1                1            22            4
         1                1            23            4
         1                2            11            4
```

I want to Update IndentHeader table StatusID = 4 when all the Items in the IndentDetail table (based on the IndentID) ItemstatusID becomes 4 otherwise I want to Update IndentHeader StatusID = 3. In the Condition I need to give POID. Based on the POID, the corresponding Indent is considered for both the IndentHeader and IndentDetail table. My desired Result should be like this:

IndentHeader:

```
 IndentID        StatusID 
--------         ------   
    1             4      
    2             3
```

How to achieve this? Please help me.

Hi all, this is my update command. But it update both the StatusID in IndentHeader as 4.

```
   UPDATE STR_IndentHeader
            SET StatusID = IID
            FROM
            (SELECT 
            STR_IndentDetail.IndentID, MIN(ItemStatusID) AS 'IID'
            FROM 
            STR_IndentDetail INNER JOIN PUR_POIndent PP
            ON PP.IndentID = STR_IndentDetail.IndentID
            AND PP.ItemID = STR_IndentDetail.ItemID
                        WHERE ItemStatusID = 4 AND PP.POID = 1
            GROUP BY STR_IndentDetail.IndentID) ID 
            WHERE ID.IndentID = STR_IndentHeader.IndentID
```

I need all your valuable contributions. please help me...

Comment: Do you know the UPDATE command at all? If so, you should at least attempt this and show us your attempt.

Comment: @Andrew: I posted my update query. please have a look at it.

Comment: What do you actually mean when you say "Here I want to pass only the POID, So the remainings should happen above as following the table relationships" ? It does not make sense.

Comment: @Hugh: In the Condition I need to give POID. So based on the corresponding IndentID to the POID in the POIndent table, Update Query should get executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My *[revised]* solution use one [ALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213254.aspx) subquery to check ItemStatusID condition:

```
DECLARE @MyPOID INT = 1;

DECLARE @IndentHeader TABLE
(
    IndentID INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,StatusID INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT  @IndentHeader 
VALUES  (1,5);
INSERT  @IndentHeader 
VALUES  (2,5);
INSERT  @IndentHeader 
VALUES  (3,5);

DECLARE @IndentDetail TABLE
(
    IndentID INT NOT NULL
    ,ItemID INT NOT NULL
    ,ItemStatusID INT NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY(IndentID, ItemID)
);
INSERT  @IndentDetail
VALUES  (1,22,4);
INSERT  @IndentDetail
VALUES  (1,23,4);
INSERT  @IndentDetail
VALUES  (2,11,4);
INSERT  @IndentDetail
VALUES  (2,12,3);
INSERT  @IndentDetail
VALUES  (2,13,3);
INSERT  @IndentDetail
VALUES  (3,22,3);

DECLARE @POIndent TABLE
(
    POID INT
    ,IndentID INT NOT NULL
    ,ItemID INT NOT NULL
    ,ItemStatusID INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT  @POIndent 
VALUES  (1,1,22,4);
INSERT  @POIndent 
VALUES  (1,1,23,4);
INSERT  @POIndent 
VALUES  (1,2,11,4);
INSERT  @POIndent 
VALUES  (2,3,22,4);

SELECT  *
FROM    @IndentHeader h;
SELECT  *
FROM    @IndentDetail d;
SELECT  *
FROM    @POIndent po;

UPDATE  @IndentHeader 
SET     StatusID = CASE WHEN 4 = ALL(SELECT d.ItemStatusID FROM @IndentDetail d WHERE d.IndentID = h.IndentID) THEN 4 ELSE 3 END
FROM    @IndentHeader h
WHERE   h.IndentID IN (SELECT po.IndentID FROM @POIndent po WHERE po.POID = @MyPOID);

SELECT  *
FROM    @IndentHeader h;
```

Comment: Yes. But it updates all the IndentID's StatusID. But I want to Update only the IndentID exists for the Corresponding POID in the POINdent table.

Comment: @thevan: This is a valuable starting point. It would be polite and correct to upvote event if this is not the final solution.

Comment: @Sahleen: thank you sahleen. this statement gives the correct answer for my problem. thank you...

Comment: @sahleen - I've never used (or knew) `ALL`. +1 for teaching me a new trick.

Answer (score 2):

The gist of it is to

- find the minimum `ItemStatusID` for each `IndentID`
- Join this back with `IndentHeader`
- Use these in an `UPDATE FROM` statement

#### SQL Statement

```
UPDATE  IndentHeader
SET     StatusID = ihd.ItemStatusID
FROM    IndentHeader ih
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  ItemStatusID = MIN(id.ItemStatusID)
                    , ih.IndentID
            FROM    IndentHeader ih
                    INNER JOIN IndentDetail id ON id.IndentID = ih.IndentID
                    INNER JOIN POIndent pi ON pi.IndentID = id.IndentID
            WHERE   pi.POID = 1     
            GROUP BY
                    ih.IndentID     
        ) ihd ON ihd.IndentID = ih.IndentID
```

#### Test script

```
;WITH IndentHeader (IndentID, StatusID) AS (
    SELECT 1, 5      
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 5
)
, IndentDetail (IndentID, ItemID, ItemStatusID) AS (
    SELECT 1, 22, 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 23, 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 11, 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 12, 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 13, 3
)
, POIndent (POID, IndentID, ItemID, ItemStatusID) AS (
    SELECT 1, 1, 22, 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 1, 23, 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 2, 11, 4
)
--UPDATE    IndentHeader
--SET       StatusID = ihd.ItemStatusID
SELECT  ih.IndentID, ihd.ItemStatusID
FROM    IndentHeader ih
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  ItemStatusID = MIN(id.ItemStatusID)
                    , ih.IndentID
            FROM    IndentHeader ih
                    INNER JOIN IndentDetail id ON id.IndentID = ih.IndentID
                    INNER JOIN POIndent pi ON pi.IndentID = id.IndentID
            WHERE   pi.POID = 1     
            GROUP BY
                    ih.IndentID     
        ) ihd ON ihd.IndentID = ih.IndentID
```

Comment: mmm... you have edited your question to include your current query. At first sight, it looks identical to what I propose but AFAIK, the query is valid. I'll have to work out some testscript

Comment: @thevan: the testscript outputs ItemStatusID 4 for IndentID 1 and ItemStatusID 3 for IndentID 2. Is this not what you need?

Comment: @thevan: the testscript outputs ItemStatusID 4 for IndentID 1 and ItemStatusID 3 for IndentID 2. Is this not what you need?

Comment: @thevan: This is a valuable starting point. It would be polite and correct to upvote event if this is not the final solution.

Comment: @thevan - don't mention it but I still puzzled by why this did not work for you.

Comment: @Lieven: we are taking the min value. so 4 is the minimum value it updates but we should not take the minimum value. we need to find some other logic for that.